# How can I use print and not have spaces added between arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(1,n+1):
    print(" "*(n-i),"#"*i)
```

Is my attempt to print:

```
     #
    ##
   ###
  ####
 #####
######
```

My solution is printing the following result instead:

```
      #
     ##
    ###
   ####
  #####
 ######
```

An extra space before every line is added and hence the pattern is shifted right by one " ".

How can I use print and not have spaces added between arguments?

Answer (score 6):

`print` inserts a  between each argument, add `sep=''`:

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(1,n+1):
    print(" "*(n-i),"#"*i, sep="")
```

or use `format`-strings:

```
for i in range(1,n+1):
    print("{:>{}s}".format("#"*i, n))
```

Comment: Another option would be to concatenate the two arguments into one string rather than having `print` do it for you. Just use a `+` instead of the `,`.

Comment: @Blckknght Ha, my answer exactly!

Answer (score 1):

The `print()` function inserts a space between arguments.

You could get around this by just passing one argument - the result of concatenating the arguments.

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(1,n+1):
    print(" "*(n-i) + "#"*i)
```

---

With `n = 5`:

```
    #
   ##
  ###
 ####
#####
```

Answer (score 1):

Change code to:

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(1,n+1):
    print(" "*(n-i) + "#"*i)
```

The use of the ',' instead of a '+' in the print statement causes an extra space to appear between concatenated terms